# Backends to use for multimedia in Qt5

Tags: c++, linux, qt5, backend, qtmultimedia

What are available and reliable multimedia backends to use with Qt5 for media playback on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about backends rather than gstreamer for linux, but you can try to integrate [QmlVlc project](https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVlc) into your code. You can find a demo [here](https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVlcDemo). It uses vlc for playing video. I successfully used this project for my purposes under Android. You can also try [QtAV](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV), it uses ffmpeg. From my experience it worked on Android as well, but there were issues with hanging UI. It might have needed more work to properly integrate though, but I didn't want to spend time on it, at least it was easy to try.

I know you were not asking for Android libs, but by using on Android I mean native (C++) code, so no Java was used.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Gstreamer Qt bindings](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/qt-gstreamer.html)

Comment: I tried but it takes a lot of CPU resources. My platform is BeagleBone Black running under Debian Jessie.

Comment: @Lazar, so uhm.. , In fact, I do not know other multimedia backends to use with Qt5 on Linux. About CPU resource question, maybe you should find where is the bottlenect, maybe a hardware acceleration is needed.